# Timeout error connecting to Atlas mongoDB from a container

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, containers, mongodb-atlas

My application can connect to my Atlas mongodb when I run it on local without a container.

When I put my application in a container I am unable to access the Atlas mongodb.

I have whitelisted all IP's.

```
        self.myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@mongodbscrapperconf-lctzq.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true&authSource=admin)
```

I have tried both to connect to my Atlas database on local with my container and running my container in GCP. In both cases I am getting a timeout error from mongoDB.

My DockerFile is looking like

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
COPY ./host.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
RUN update-ca-certificates
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python ./controller.py cloud
```

requirements.txt

```
iso4217
validators
pymongo
pymongo[srv]
flask
lxml
flask-cors
configparser
```

UPDATED: I found out that the connection is encrypted and the connection need to accept SSL certificates. I have tried this but Atlas is still refusing the connection.

Comment: try adding dnspython to your requirements.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue by adding

```
pymongo[tls,srv]
```

To the requirements.txt

This is the resulting requirements.txt

```
iso4217
validators
pymongo[tls,srv]
flask
lxml
flask-cors
configparser
```